# Difference BETWEEN adding CHECK ON a COLUMN AND CHECK CONSTRAINT ON THE same COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl

While comparing table structure by using XML, we're getting difference in table structures of same business logic of check constraints. 
Please check and explain us the difference.

```
CREATE TABLE ESWAR(ID INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR2(10));

ALTER TABLE ESWAR ADD CHECK("NAME" IS NOT NULL);
```

TABLE definition AFTER adding THE CHECK:

```
create table ESWAR
(
  id   INTEGER not null,
  name VARCHAR2(10) not null
);
```

DROP THE CREATED SYSTEM CONSTRAINT

```
SELECT T.CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM ALL_Constraints t WHERE t.TABLE_NAME='ESWAR' AND T.SEARCH_CONDITION_VC='"NAME" IS NOT NULL';--SYS_C00179403

ALTER TABLE ESWAR DROP CONSTRAINT SYS_C00179403;
```

AGAIN CREATING CHECK CONSTRAINT AS BELOW

```
ALTER TABLE ESWAR
  ADD CONSTRAINT CONST_ESWAR_CHECK
  CHECK ("NAME" IS NOT NULL);
```

TABLE DEFINITION AFTER creating constraint:

```
create table ESWAR
(
  id   INTEGER not null,
  name VARCHAR2(10)
);

-- Create/Recreate check constraints 
alter table ESWAR
  add constraint CONST_ESWAR_CHECK
  check ("NAME" IS NOT NULL);

SELECT * FROM ALL_Constraints t WHERE t.TABLE_NAME='ESWAR' AND T.SEARCH_CONDITION_VC='"NAME" IS NOT NULL';---CONST_ESWAR_CHECK
```

Comment: When you say "adding a check on a column", you are actually adding a *check constraint*. There is no such thing as a "check".

Comment: For the specific case of a not null check constraint, the basic `NOT NULL` is better than an explicit check constraint because the optimizer is aware of `NOT NULL` columns but does not look at other user-defined check constraint definitions.

Comment: I agree with you William Robertson, but my main concern is why table definition is getting different.

Comment: What is different exactly? In my tests I can create any number of anonymous (system-named) check constraints as `(NAME IS NOT NULL)` or `("NAME" IS NOT NULL)`, and none of them make the column actually not-null in the standard, useful sense. Otherwise the only difference is the name, which is either `CONST_ESWAR_CHECK` if you name it yourself or system-generated if you don't. You mention XML but I don't see any.

Answer (score 2):

Considering:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ESWAR ADD CHECK("NAME" IS NOT NULL);
```

and

```sql
ALTER TABLE ESWAR ADD CONSTRAINT CONST_ESWAR_CHECK CHECK ("NAME" IS NOT NULL);
```

The constraints are functionally the same; however, one will be generated with a system-generated name (i.e. `SYS_C00179403`) and the other will generated with a user-defined name (i.e. `CONST_ESWAR_CHECK`).

You can use exactly the same options if you create the [constraint in-line](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE) within a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ESWAR(
  ID   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

or

```sql
CREATE TABLE ESWAR(
  ID   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(10) CHECK( NAME IS NOT NULL )
);
```

or

```sql
CREATE TABLE ESWAR(
  ID   INT
       CONSTRAINT ESWAR__ID__NN NOT NULL
                                INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
                                NOT DEFERRABLE
                                ENABLE
                                VALIDATE
       CONSTRAINT ESWAR__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY
                                INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
                                NOT DEFERRABLE
                                ENABLE
                                VALIDATE,
  NAME VARCHAR2(10)
       CONSTRAINT ESWAR__NAME__NN NOT NULL
                                INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
                                NOT DEFERRABLE
                                ENABLE
                                VALIDATE
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d16fbb80de14e7e8cc933529731d89bb)